# Split column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file in which one of the column is a multi-value field, for example:

```
Col1|Col2
rec1|xyz#tew
rec2|
rec3|jkl#qwer
```

I need to split the Col2 based on delimiter, and following is the code which I am using:

```
x = ['Col1','Col2']
df[x] = (df[x].apply(lambda c: c.str.split('#',expand=True))
```

With this code I am getting following error : "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'series' "

I tried using replace and fillna, but no luck, can someone please help in correcting the above code

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Will you please provide a sample of your dataframe with `print(df.head(5).to_Dict())`?

Comment: The point of using series.str string methods is that you don't have to `apply` them or use `lambda`. Have you tried just `df['col2'].str.split('#',expand=True)`?

Comment: if I use df['col2'].str.split('#',expand=True) then it gives error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'"

Comment: @Kunal did you see my comment? :)

Comment: @KunalSharma what's your expected output?

Comment: output :
Col1|Col2|Col3
rec1|xyz|tew
rec2||
rec3|jkl|qwer

Comment: @richardec here is sample you required: {'Col1': {0: 'rec1', 1: 'rec2', 2: 'rec3'}, 'Col2': {0: 'xyz#tew', 1: nan, 2: 'jkl#qwer'}}

Answer (score 0):

First, we'll need to replace the NaN values in a clever manner:

```
>> df["Col2"] = df["Col2"].fillna("#")
```

Now, split the strings in the "Col2" column:

```
>> df["Col2"] = df["Col2"].str.split("#", n=1)  # n=1 to make sure every list has 2 values
>> df
   Col1         Col2
0  rec1   [xyz, tew]
1  rec2         [, ]
2  rec3  [jkl, qwer]
```

Now, merge your original dataframe with a new dataframe created from the lists of the previous step

```
>> df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df["Col2"].values.tolist())) # .add_prefix('col_'))
```

You can add a prefix if you want to name your columns (add `.add_prefix('Col_')` at the end, for example). Drop your old "Col2":

```
>> df = df.drop("Col2", axis=1)
>> df

   Col1    0     1
0  rec1  xyz   tew
1  rec2           
2  rec3  jkl  qwer
```